# Efficient way to remove delimiters from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have to write several lines of code to remove delimiters from a string. Is there a more efficient way to remove all delimiters? Thanks.

```
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    str = str.replace(/ /g,'');
    str = str.replace(/\*/g, '');
    str = str.replace(/_/g, '');
    str = str.replace(/#/g, '');
    //etc....
```

Comment: You can't just remove delimiters this way, they are paired and possibly escaped as a literal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use character class:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[ *_#]/g, '');
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: To clarify, the `[]` brackets mean "match any one character that is inside these brackets." In this case, the regular expression will match any character that is a space, `*`, `_`, or `#`.